# Why can seemingly equivalent code using "yield from" with a shared generator lead to StopIteration?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to understand the behaviour of the keyword `yield from` and find it so hard to explain...

Here is the setting:

**Case 1** - If I run this snippet, there is no exception.

```py
gen = (x for x in range(10))

def func():
    yield from gen

F21 = func()
F22 = func()
next(F21)
next(F22)
```

**Case 2** - This time instead of introducing variables `F21` and `F22`, I hit the `StopIteration` exception.

```py
gen = (x for x in range(10))

def func():
    yield from gen

next(func())
next(func())
```

Why is there a difference between the two cases?

Comment: Everything you show is using the same `gen`; once you've extracted all ten items from it, `StopIteration` is all you'll be able to get.  Your final lines of code would have worked just fine if you had executed them earlier.

Comment: @jasonharper: Case 2 raises `StopIteration` on the second `next(func())` even if you run `gen = (x for x in range(10))` between case 1 and 2, so this is not explainable by an exhausted generator.

Comment: running `gen = (...)` outside of `func` does not update it's value inside `func`, but if you run case 2 first - same result. It's like Python is not referentially transparent, `F21` and `func()` do not have same value or something.

Comment: Additional unintuitive behaviour: When replacing the generator expression by a generator function that also prints the generated values, we see that the StopIteration happens even before the second value 1 has been generated.

Comment: It's interesting that in case 1, if you insert `del F21` before `next(F22)`, you do get the StopIteration error. What that has in common with case 2 is that the line that generates the error comes right after a generator object returned by `func()` has gone to zero refcount.

Comment: have updated the question to avoid ambiguity. sorry for that.